# Windows Command Prompt Input Explaination

Tags: c++, command, line

Could you help me understand this input into the command line :

type direct-mapped.input | mem_sim 8 2 2 1 2 1 2 2

direct-mapped.input is a file with info that is read in a cpp file. mem_sim is the cpp file that has been compiled and the numbers following mem_sim are inputs into the cpp file.

Also how are these values stored in the cpp file?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In *nix and Windows operating systems, the numbers are not stored in the CPP file; nothing will modify the source file.

The operating system stores the numbers in an *argument list* that is passed to the `main` function in your program (a.k.a. the 2nd parameter to `main`).

```
ArgC  |  ArgV
--------------
0     |  mem_sim
1     |  8
2     |  2
3     |  2
4     |  1
5     |  2
6     |  2
```

Comment: Thank that makes sense, but what happens with the direct-mapped.input. Thanks

Comment: The contents of the `direct-mapped.input` will be piped into `cin` of your program.  So when your program reads from `cin`, it will be reading from `direct-mapped.input`.